# Service layer and repositories relationship

Tags: c#, service, repository, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

What makes more sense. Having a service layer reference multiple repositories (acting as a facade), or having a repository group multiple related entities together. For example I have the following entities and I'm not sure how to structure things.

**Entities (POCO's)**

1. Survey
2. SurveyGroup
3. SurveyQuestion
4. SurveyAnswer

**Q1.**  Should each of these entities have their own respository? SurveyQuestion cannot exist without being in a SurveyGroup, and SurveyGroup cannot exist without being in a Survey.

**Q2.**  Should I make one Repository for Survey, SurveyGroup, and SurveyQuestion, and an additional one for SurveyAnswers?

**Q3.** Should I make a separate repository for each one and create one service class (SurveyService) that references them all?

I'm not sure what is considered "best practice" for something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general rule of thumb in DDD is to create a repository for every [Aggregate Root](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/16/ddd-aggregates-and-aggregate-roots.aspx).

In your example, it looks like `Survey` would be the Aggregate Root, so create a `SurveyRepository`.

Answer (score 1):

*Rule of thumb* (i.e. standard) is to have repositories for entities which have identity (e.g. Primary Key). In other words, such entities can have CRUD operations [at least] defined in **their own** repositories.

Repository is not necessary for entities which are not *"first-class"* entities and cannot have CRUD defined on their own. Thus, they must be handled using dependency mapping (other "first-class" entity mappings take care of them).

However, you may want to decrease number of repositories in your project, and that's when you start looking at alternative (non-standard) ways to group entities.

Conclusion: if you want to be standard, have as many repositories as many self-contained entities you have. Concrete answer depends on the entities listed in your question, and I think you will be able to judge on your own having this information at hand.

Previous answer may [theoretically] lead to repositories handling several entities needlessly, and headaches of finding/locating the entity handling/mapping code in the future.

[I used terms defined by Fowler, M. - *identity*, *dependency mapping*]

Comment: If your repository handles something needlessly then you probably incorrectly defined aggregates boundries. Repository should be used only to obtain and persist whole aggregates which defines and forces the consistency of the domain - it's invariants. Making repositories for entities not being an aggregate-root would lead to violating the invariants.

Comment: Aggregate root is a function of time and has a changing tree/composite structure, especially if requirements change during development. Keeping up with this changing nature would mean changing repositories and tracking the implementation locations in code. Besides, obtaining an aggregate from domain will look the same if the aggregate root repository interacts with other repositories to construct the aggregate. For this sole purpose you don't need to have repositories only for aggregate roots.

Comment: You are talking about DAO, not repository. You completely missed the point of the latter. And of course - one repository can use several DAOs to compose the aggregate.

Comment: Good point! but no, I am talking about Repository implementation. Repository usually comes from abstract factory if DAO change is foreseen, thus repository often has factory reference which creates repositories. I was suggesting to separate repositories for entities which support identity mapping, but still group dependency mappings inside the same repository. On the other hand, DAO will have both "first-class" (identity mapped) and "second-class" (dependency mapped) entities separately. In other words, I suggest a little different grouping, or maybe a different way to identify aggregates.